# Google Maps v2 XML error and R cannot resolved to a variable

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

i am trying to create a google map with gps that show the user location whenever and wherever he moves. at my xml file, there is the error "Error parsing XML: XML declaration not well-formed" and at my MainActivity java file, "R cannot be resolved to a variable" at first there are no such errors but one time i clean my project then the error appears and never go away. i tried deleting the line "" but it cause more errors. 
then everytime i save my project, it will have two more errors in addition to the previous two. "Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag fragment" and "XML version "1.0 encoding=" is not supported, only XML 1.0 is supported" in the XML also. after i clean mt project, this last two will be gone for a while until i save again
i heard the XML will affect the R file but i am not sure what cause the R in this case.

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0 encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

android manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.studenthealthapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<permission android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-features
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.studenthealthapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API key value" />

</application>
```

Main Java file

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if(googleMap == null)
    {
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if(googleMap != null)
        {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }

}

private void setUpMap() 
{
    //Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    //Get locationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    //Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    //Get current location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    //set map type
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    //Get latitude of the current location
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    //Get longitude of the current location
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    //Create a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    //Show the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    //Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!"));

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

i know that Google Map API v1 cannot be used and v2 which i am using need to be connected to a real android device. can anyone confirm this face for me? because my application has a lot of other part that don't need Google maps so how do we test our application? some on emulator some on android phone? i have not tested on my phone yet due to the errors, so i assume i just need to connect my laptop with my phone and run, while selecting the device? i any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this

```
 xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

for fragment

Also change

```
<?xml version="1.0 encoding="utf-8"?>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

If you have errors in any of your resource files R.java will not be generated. SO make sure there are no errors in your resource files. Clean and build project.

You are also missing the below in application tag of manifest which is new requirement after the google play services update rev 13.

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: it shows no error at first, but after i run errors start to appear, i dont really understand them. since it is different error, i ask a new question about it. if you will, could you help me with this? thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21327914/android-google-maps-v2-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field-name-bound-to-nam