# Android google maps v2 cannot be resolved or is not a field, "name" bound to namespace

Tags: android, google-maps

i am creating a android which shows the user location with Google Maps through gps. when i run my program i have the following errors.

activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field, displayMap cannot be resolved or is not a field
main cannot be resolved or is not a field. at first this error did not appear but after i save or clean my project, it appears

i have change the displayMap and save, clean my project in strings and xml file. but the error is still there.

Attribute "name" bound to namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" was already specified for element "meta-data"  in my android manifest

Parser exception for /MyAppName/AndroidManifest.xml: Attribute "name" bound to namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" was already specified for element "meta-data". the resource for this is my ApplicationNameApp(my project name)

does that means i must change the "name" under meta data?

strings file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">StudentHealthApp</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="displayMap">Google Map Display</string>
</resources>
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/displayMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Android Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.studenthealthapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<permission android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-features
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.studenthealthapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API key value" 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

Main Java file

```
import android.R;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if(googleMap == null)
    {
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.displayMap)).getMap();

        if(googleMap != null)
        {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }

}

private void setUpMap() 
{
    //Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    //Get locationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    //Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    //Get current location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    //set map type
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    //Get latitude of the current location
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    //Get longitude of the current location
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    //Create a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    //Show the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    //Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!"));

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

i have added google play services as a project, google-play-services_lib appear as a seperate project folder then my application in eclipse. then i add to my libarary by Project -> Properties -> Android -> Library, Add -> google-play-services_lib

Comment: is it compile time problem ..?

Comment: yes, when i run my project, the problem occur. now it only left displayMap cannot be resolved or is not a field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyAZUoTQoHQwP25j0L_hTIUsXjxWmkFi3vg" 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

to

```
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyAZUoTQoHQwP25j0L_hTIUsXjxWmkFi3vg"/>
   <meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Remove

```
  import android.R;
```

Instead you need

```
  import com.example.studenthealthapp.R;
```

But if its in the same package then there is no need for import.

Also if you have errors in your resources files R.java will not be generated. So if any errors fix them and clean and build project.

Comment: thank you very much for the fast reply. the errors related to meta data are gone. only left those that are "cannot be resolved or is not a field" i am searching for answers now. thanks again

Comment: @Myst remove `import android.R;`

Comment: @Myst you also need to check the availability of google play services and then initialize google map object

Answer (score 0):

remove import android.R;

and **import your package name.R** file

```
      @Override
        protected void onResume() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onResume();

       int resultCode =                GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

      if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
    "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }else{
       GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
         }

            }
```

Comment: if its in the same package then there is no need to import. the problem was he imported android.R;

Comment: i change my import android.R; to import com.example.studenthealthapp.R; and the error was solved. the only error left is, displayMap cannot be resolved or is not a field. in the past when i faced this i change the name in strings and XML and it worked. but this time it does not work

Comment: @Myst clean and build your project once and make sure you have inflated the right layout

Comment: @Myst <string name="displayMap">Google Map Display</string>           fragment for map has same id displayMap that is why there is a conflict please change the id

Comment: wait. there are no errors now. i think it is because i just saved. ok i going to run on my phone and see the result. Thanks

Comment: when i run, it say Google Play services is not supported. which is what i expected based on what i heard. it is my first time developing this. what i don't know is how to run on a real phone? i just plug the wire from my laptop to my phone. i do not know any other steps. i would prefer it could run on an emulator. i going to research on this

Comment: on which api level are you testing does it have GooglePlayServices installed

Comment: @Myst you use http://www.genymotion.com/ to test it on emulator. google maps require google play services. So your decide phone/emulator requires the smae to run maps an on emulators it is 4.3 and above i guess.

Comment: i have downloaded genymotion. but i have trouble knowing how to downloaded the plugin.

Comment: i dont know about genymotion but u can use http://www.bluestacks.com/ very fast emaulator and it  also supports map.

Comment: so it support Google Play Services/Google Maps?ok i try it out

Comment: my comp is quite slow for some reason. i am still trying out blueStacks and genymotion now. but i have a android phone too but i also do not know how to select my phone on eclpise too

Comment: i am currently using following http://josephmak2007.blogspot.in/2011/02/making-your-android-app-run-on-real.html to run on real device. not sure whether it will work but since i have trouble with emulator, i try this to see if i can display my map.

Comment: i did not exactly follow the link above but i did run and i am able to run on my phone. the app did appear but it says "unfortunetly, MyApplicationNameApp has stopped" which means it does run but there is a error in my code? this also appear in my emulator when there is a code error

Comment: i run my other application and it works. so i think i can run my application on phone. but my map application has errors. but now when i open my project in eclipse it shows the error An error has occurred. See error log for more details.java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: ignore the above "java.util.ConcurrentModificationException" error. i solved it thanks to other question. now i am focusing on my map

Comment: @user2107192, when do i implement and call the OnResume method. do i call it on my oncreate method when starting? before or after setUpMapIfNeeded?